# simple drag and drop to target as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, drag-and-drop, drag, target

I'd like to make a draggable movieclip target another movieclip (drop target).

It doesn't need to have a reusuable function (i.e. event.target not necessary) and it doesn't need to be part of an array.

I can't see why the code below won't work. I've tried using an assign symbol (=) instead of equals (==) in places but this makes no difference.

Any feedback much appreciated.

```
//Creating variables to store original x/y position of draggable movieclip (my_mc2):
var startX:Number;
var startY:Number;

//Enabling hand cursor over draggable mc:
my_mc2.buttonMode = true;

//Adding event listeners for mouse up and mouse down.
my_mc2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
my_mc2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);

//Drag function (mouse down):
function drag(event:MouseEvent):void {
startX = my_mc2.x;
startY = my_mc2.y;
my_mc2.startDrag();
}

//Drop function (mouse up):
function drop(event:MouseEvent):void {
my_mc2.stopDrag();
if (my_mc2.x == target_mc2.x && my_mc2.y == target_mc2.y) {
    my_mc2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
    } else {
    my_mc2.x == startX;
    my_mc2.y == startY;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `target_mc2` to be `my_mc2` target. There is very little chance that `my_mc2` and `target_mc2` get exactly the same coordinates. By consequence you should decide on an area around `target_mc2`.

```
my_mc2.buttonMode = true;
var startX:int = my_mc2.x;
var startY:int = my_mc2.y;
const D:int = 20;

function drag(e:MouseEvent):void {
    e.target.startDrag();
}

function drop(e:MouseEvent):void {
    stopDrag();
    if (my_mc2.x > target_mc2.x - D && my_mc2.x < target_mc2.x + D && my_mc2.y > target_mc2.y - D &&  my_mc2.y < target_mc2.y + D) {
        my_mc2.x = target_mc2.x;
        my_mc2.y = target_mc2.y;
    } else {
        my_mc2.x = startX;
        my_mc2.y = startY;
    }
}

my_mc2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);
```

Comment: Sorry, it seems this code is coming up in the debug window as the reason why error 1009 is appearing. As part of the successful drop function, my timeline jumps (gotoAndPlay). From that point on, anytime I click the stage (or anything on it) in the SWF, the output tells me I have error 1009 and points to the drop function. The Debug Console points to the specific line, which in your code example above is the 'if' line. To be honest, I came across this in another file so I decided to start afresh. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: btw, I've traced everything in that 'if' section of the drop function. Nothing has come up as null.

Comment: yay! have found the answer (but I don't know the theory behind it). I needed to extend both the drag and drop objects (my_mc2 and target_mc2 in example above) in the timeline so that they still existed when the stage was clicked later on. To get around that, I just set their visible property to false. Tis a learning curve!

Comment: this probably amounts to the 'theory'. I had the drop function tied to an event-listener for the stage (not for the drag item). I read somewhere that it was better to do that. Anyway, aside from removing the event-listener for startdrag, I also removed the one for stopdrag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question with alternative code - although it still isn't clear to me why the previous code wouldn't work. I guess it has something to do with either of these:
    if (my_mc2.x == target_mc2.x && my_mc2.y == target_mc2.y)....
    my_mc2.x == startX;
    my_mc2.y == startY;

Anyway, for any other AS3 newbies out there looking for a simple workaround, this works for me. (Yes, it is a reusable function, better practice.)

```
circleMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUp);
circleMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropIt);
circleMC.startX = circleMC.x;
circleMC.startY = circleMC.y;
circleMC.buttonMode = true;

function pickUp(event:MouseEvent):void{
// no longer need to keep track of startX & startY here as already been done above
event.target.startDrag(true);
}

function dropIt(event:MouseEvent):void{
event.target.stopDrag();
// check to see if the event target is touching target_mc using hitTestObject
if(event.target.hitTestObject(target_mc)){
    event.target.buttonMode = false;
    event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUp);
    }
    else
    // move back to original position
    {
    circleMC.x = circleMC.startX;
    circleMC.y = circleMC.startY;
    }
}
```

Comment: For anyone reading this later, I went with the suggestion from helloflash but also had to create a bounding box and made sure my drag and drop objects extended in the rest of the timeline. Otherwise the file ran into problems. See comments above.

Answer (score 0):

thanks again to helloflash for your answer.

Just wanted to update this topic for anyone else trying it out....

when you test it, if you drag the object off (or touching) the edge of the stage, it no longer repositions itself to its original coordinates.

to get around this, create a bounding box to limit where it can be dragged. This box will be smaller than the stage. The exact dimensions will take some trial-and-error to fit your project. It's easy to do though. Add a new rectangle within the startDrag second property (false, new Rectangle (startx, starty, rectanglewidth, rectangleheight), like so:

```
function drag(e:MouseEvent):void {
e.target.startDrag(false, new Rectangle (200, 200, 600, 300));
}
```